# Disable user from interacting in input field, dropdown and toggle in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a gameobject and it has a child of input field, dropdown and toggle. What I wanted is to write a script to prevent user from interacting on input field, dropdown and toggle at the same time. Is there a function in gameobject or do I have to call the child component individually and disable them.

[image]

Comment: [`UI.Selectable.interactable`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable-interactable.html) ?

Answer (score 2):

Let **gameObject** in following example be the target panel GameObject.
Then you can simply go through all *Selectable* components in children and disable them.

```
var uiElements = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Selectable>();
foreach (var uiElement in uiElements)
{
    uiElement.interactable = false;
}
```